# Manipulate : Spacing and Background

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Please Consider :

```
 Manipulate[Rasterize[Graphics[{
    Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 10}],
    Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, L}],
    Green, Rectangle[{2, 0}, {4, M}],
    Blue, Rectangle[{4, 0}, {6, S}]},
    ImageSize -> {200, 270},
    ImageSize -> 50]],
    Control@{{L, 1, Style["L", Red, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
    ControlType -> Slider, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 200},
    Control@{{M, 1, Style["M", Green, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
    ControlType -> Slider, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 200},
    Control@{{S, 1, Style["S", Blue, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
    ControlType -> Slider, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 200}]
```

[image]

- Can I change the Background Color : Black instead of White for example.
- Why is there so much empty space on the right. I have never been able to match the slider size with the width of the Manipulate being just enveloping the graphics contained?

Comment: Hmm.. I can control the grey part, but not the white.

Comment: @Yoda, I am interested ! How ? And can you do anything for the superficial space on the right :-) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `Paneled -> False` in `Manipulate`, it shrinks the white space around the `Graphics`. The remaining white can be easily set to have a different background by setting it appropriately in the `Graphics[...]` command. You can also style the outer panel by setting the background in the `BaseStyle` for `Manipulate`. Here's a slight modification of your code:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 10}], Red, 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, L}], Green, Rectangle[{2, 0}, {4, M}], Blue, 
   Rectangle[{4, 0}, {6, S}]}, ImageSize -> {200, 300}, 
  Background -> LightOrange], 
 Control@{{L, 1, Style["L", Red, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Control@{{M, 1, Style["M", Green, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Control@{{S, 1, Style["S", Blue, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, BaseStyle -> {Background -> LightPurple},
  Paneled -> False, ImageMargins -> 10]
```

[image]

I hadn't noticed in my previous example that the labels had moved slightly upwards. In any case, belisarius' suggestion of using `ImageSize -> Small` is simpler, so I've adopted it.

Comment: so no way to have the Label on the side to make it more compost vertically ? Already Awesome...

Comment: The `BaseStyle` option does not work on my system (MMa 8.0.1 on Windows XP 32 bit).

Comment: @500 I figured out a way to change the white to a different color. Please see my edit. I think using `ImageSize -> Small` like in belisarius' code is simpler than trying to wrestle with placing the Labels correctly with `LabeledSlider`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't have a windows system, so I can't check that.. Sorry :(

Comment: @yoda I have figured out the reason: the `Background` option did not work because of the default `Paneled->True` of `Manipulate`. Setting it to `False` as in the last edit makes `Background` working!

Comment: @Alexey, THank You Paneled option enables me to get it all Black :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you overused the ImageSize option:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 10}], Red, 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, L}], Green, Rectangle[{2, 0}, {4, M}], Blue, 
   Rectangle[{4, 0}, {6, S}]}, ImageSize -> {200, 300}],

 Control@{{L, 1, Style["L", Red, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Control@{{M, 1, Style["M", Green, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Control@{{S, 1, Style["S", Blue, Bold, 24]}, Range[10], 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Small, ControlPlacement -> Top,
    DefaultBaseStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I still hope to have the slider all the way till the end keeping the Label at slider height :-)

Comment: @500 The problem is that "Labeled" puts a large box from the visible number till the right margin, and seems there is no way to resize it.